# Custom indexOf for strings javascript with regex

Tags: javascript, beginner, interview-questions, regex, ecmascript-6

I was wondering how efficient my code is creating custom indexOf for strings in JavaScript using regex instead of looping with a `for` statement the whole way in most solution I find and I believe this got \$O(1)\$ since no loop is needed.

The idea is to use regex that put either the key or any list of word that is not key; this way I know that the value will be either in `arr[0]` or `arr[1]`.  I also check using regex earlier whether the key exist in the value or not; this way I created non-looping indexOf with regex. This way I just return `0` if the key is in `arr[0]` or `arr[0].length` if it not in `arr[0]`.

```
function findindex(value,key){
  let regex = RegExp( "((?!"+key+").)+|"+key , "ig" ); //regex for separating keys in the array
  let regex2 = RegExp(key,"ig");  // regex for checking if the key is exist in the value or not

  //first check before looping whether key is available in array or not
  if( !regex2.test(value) || value.length < key.length ){
    return -1;
  }

  let arr  = value.match(regex); //make an array  

  //alternative with condition statement
  return ( arr[0] === key || regex2.test(arr[0]) ) ? 0 : arr[0].length; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Too sad, it's not O(1).
There is a cost for:

- Constructing the regex into a DFA
- Calling `test()` or `match()` on the regex for the value

Complexities:

- A well implemented regex construction will be `O(M)` where M is the length of the key.
- While test/matching it afterwards will be `O(N)` where N is the length of the value. (best case, e.g. regexes with backtracking can result in horrible complexities)

So a couple of improvements can be:

- if the key is always the same. Construct the regex for the key only once.
- first start with comparing the length of the value and key before calling the more expensive test()-match() methods.
- apart from that, the idea of a regex is ok but I don't know if it's the most understandable way of writing an indexOf.
- Reference: [Regex Complexities on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892115/whats-the-time-complexity-of-average-regex-algorithms)

Comment: I do agree that this not a really understandable way of writing indexOf, just though I could make it faster by reducing the loop. As I just learned regex I though it's a cheap way to avoid looping to get a value. never thought calling test() and match() is really expensive. thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: I wouldn't say "really expensive", in general it will be quite similar to a normal loop. And far better than a naïve implementation using 2 loops with worst case O(NM). You can have a look at some popular string search algorithms like "Rabin-Karp", "Boyer-Moore" or my favourite "Knuth-Morris-Pratt" that is construction a DFA and using it which can give you more insights in this topic.